# Accessing temp table outside Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have Stored Procedure which gives output as temp table

```
Create Proc Hello (@id int,@name nvarchar(30))
as
begin 
If (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Welcome')  Is Not Null) Drop Table #Welcome
select * into #Welcome from hello where id=@id
If (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Welcomes')  Is Not Null) Drop Table #Welcomes
select * into #Welcomes from hello where name=@name

end
```

Now I got 2 temp table as result which i will be using in dataset..

Now i need to access the this #welcome in another stored procedure ..I mean

```
    Create Proc HelloThere(@ids int,@name nvarchar(10)) 
    as
    begin 
      exec hello @id = @ids ,@name =@name

      //select * from #Welcome(Here i need to access the #Welcome so i can perform inner join something like below//

   select * from #welcome inner join Atable on #welcome.id=Atable.id

   end
```

Comment: Temporary tables are one way to share data between procedures, but not the only one, and not always the best one. See [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for a full overview, including on how you use temp tables for this.

Comment: Thanks Jereon Very helpful and informative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary tables created in a stored procedure are automatically dropped when the stored procedure completes, so the temp table will not be available to the calling stored procedure.

One method to keep the temp table around is to explicitly create the table in the calling proc (using `CREATE TABLE` or `SELECT INTO`) and then load it in the called proc:

```
CREATE PROC Hello @id int,@name nvarchar(30)
AS
INSERT INTO #Welcome SELECT * FROM hello where id=@id;
GO

CREATE PROC HelloThere(@ids int,@name nvarchar(10)) 
AS
If OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Welcome', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Welcome;

SELECT * INTO #welcome FROM hello WHERE 0 = 1;

EXEC hello @id = @ids ,@name =@name;

SELECT * FROM #welcome INNER JOIN Atable ON #welcome.id=Atable.idl

GO
```

As @JeroenMostert mentioned in comments, you can peruse http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html[How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global temporary table (2 "#") if need to use outside of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROC TEST AS
    SELECT TOP 10 * INTO ##GLOBAL_TABLE FROM SYS.all_objects
GO
EXEC TEST
SELECT * FROM ##GLOBAL_TABLE --It works
```

Just be careful that other processes that may try to use the same name and generate errors (or drop your global table and use it in another way)

You can create the table with the date you've created the procedure after (Change `##USERS` to something like `##USERS_20220101`)